# Headless chrome launcher --window-size causing error

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-headless

I need to be able to take screenshot given a certain window size. I read this blog post on [How to run Headless Chrome in Codeception](https://web.archive.org/web/20200220022511/http://phptest.club/t/how-to-run-headless-chrome-in-codeception/1544) and this page on [Getting Started with Headless Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome) but could not figure out how to resize the window at init.

I have tried to pass `--window-size` in all options below and none work:

```sh
--window-size=1280,1696
--window-size=1280x1696
--window-size 1280,1696
--window-size 1280x1696
```

*Worst of all*, now my screenshot is blank after doing this for awhile. Is there some kind of memory retained in the headless browser causing this? I have not tried to reboot my Mac yet which is probably next.

**So what is a way to take full page screenshot given window size?** In phantom.js, this is a very trivial thing.

My code is below

```js
const chromeLauncher = require('chrome-launcher');
const CDP = require('chrome-remote-interface');
const file = require('fs');

(async function() {
  async function launchChrome() {
    return await chromeLauncher.launch({
      chromeFlags: [
        '--window-size=1280,1696',
        '--disable-gpu',
        '--headless'
      ]
    });
  }
  const chrome = await launchChrome();
  const protocol = await CDP({
    port: chrome.port
  });

  const {
    DOM,
    Network,
    Page,
    Emulation,
    Runtime
  } = protocol;
  await Promise.all([Network.enable(), Page.enable(), Runtime.enable(), DOM.enable()]);

  Page.navigate({
    url: 'https://www.yahoo.com/'
  });

  Page.loadEventFired(async() => {

    console.log('Start Page.loadEventFired');
    const script1 = "document.querySelector('p').textContent"
    const result = await Runtime.evaluate({
      expression: script1
    });
    console.log(result.result.value);

    const ss = await Page.captureScreenshot({format: 'png', fromSurface: false});
    file.writeFile('output.png', ss.data, 'base64', function(err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    });

    protocol.close();
    chrome.kill(); 
  });

})();
```

If I do this in command line, it works fine:

```sh
alias chrome-canary="/Applications/Google\ Chrome\ Canary.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome\ Canary"

chrome-canary --headless --disable-gpu --screenshot --window-size=300,1696 https://www.yahoo.com/
```

#### UPDATE

I realized headless Chrome Canary is very unstable on the Mac at least. If I close down the Terminal and start it fresh, sometime it works. But then after running exactly the same script, it just hung up forever (I left overnight). I just updated everything (Chrome Canary, chrome-launcher, chrome-remote-interface) today and continue to debug. Maybe it's not its prime time yet.

Comment: I had halt problems with `'deviceScaleFactor': 0`, setting it to `1` solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK I just learnt that using `--window-size` won't work. Below works:

**Added:**

```
  Page.setDeviceMetricsOverride({
    'width': 735,
    'height': 2200,
    'deviceScaleFactor': 1,
    'mobile': false
  });
```

**Removed (caused Headless Chrome to freeze):**

```
const script1 = "document.querySelector('p').textContent"
const result = await Runtime.evaluate({
  expression: script1
});
console.log(result.result.value);
```